Yubikey not staying illuminated
I bought an old 2017 imac ( it was wiped completely due to be auctioned from a community college) and installed  ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS. My wife is trying to use it for work but the yubikey does not stay illuminated when it's plugged in tonthe usb slots. I have added the /etc/udev/70-u2f.rules per yubico. I also can interrogate the yubikey on cli with ykmam just fine. There's a functionality I'm not familiar enough with yubikeys and it being illuminated that her company website requires to be able to log in for work.
Any ideas?
